# Copying attributes from one point to another in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile

I have mapped several points on a shapefile. Some of them share the same attributes. In the attributes table I copied the attributes of the source point, select the target point with empty row, but after paste it, it creates a new row. How a can get my target point "filled" with the same attributes?

Comment: You can either copy single attributes, use the `field calculator` to set attributes, manually set them, or use the `attribute dialogue` in the layers `properties` to predefine attributes.

Comment: Thanks Erik. So there is no equivalent of a quick copy/paste? I want to reproduce a single row with 10 fields, 3 times, another row 5 times, another 4 times... Predefine will take same time as setting them one by one.

Comment: Copy & paste copies the whole feature. You could do so and move the copied feature where you need it to be.

Comment: How to do it? How to associate a copied row to a point already existed on a map but with blank row? Understand? I have 2 points, A and B. Point A is filled with all attributes. Point B, in a different location, will have the same attributes. How do I copy the entire row from A to B ?

Comment: You don't. You copy point A as a whole and move the copy to point B.

Comment: I think this is the issue. Moving to point B. Would you mind to summarize me the sequence of commands and clicks? It seems to simple but I just can't do it and can't find how.

Comment: Turn on the `advanced digitalisation tools`, then turn on editing, copy & paste, then move stuff (the symbol for the tool is quite obvious).

Comment: Thanks a lot Erik. Now it was really simple! Please make this a response.